# jQuery UI date picker query

Tags: jquery

In jquery date picker, is there any way to open the calendar of that particular year that I type in the input field? Like if I type 2015 then the 2015 calendar will open and by default 1st January will be selected. I have added the following code

```
$( "#datepickerfrom" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeYear:true,
changeMonth: true,
yearRange: "2014:+1",
});
```

but not working. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setDate option of the date picker to set any date you want

```
$('#datepickerfrom').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) to set a default date to a datepicker and calculate the difference in days on every change

```js
$("#datepickerfrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
});

$("#year").change(function () {
    $('#datepickerfrom').datepicker("option", "defaultDate", parseInt((new Date($(this).val(), 0, 1) - new Date()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 10));
    //Or use setDate to fill datepicker field
    //$('#datepickerfrom').datepicker("setDate", new Date($(this).val(), 0, 1));
    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="number"  min="1970" max="275760" value="2021" id="year">
<input type="text" id="datepickerfrom">
```